# save data in localStorage when document is unloaded

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, local-storage, google-chrome-storage, createobjecturl

I'm making a chrome extension.User can upload images to the extension.To save the data of images I am using `window.URL.createObjectURL()`.The problem is that I want to save the data about images in localStorage and use it again. But **Browsers release the data automatically when the document is unloaded**.
How can I use the data even when document is unloaded?

Comment: See examples of reading the image contents into a string, then store it in any extension storage.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an *example* below on how to save data into LocalStorage but you can read more on the usage of LocalStorage  [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

// Storing into LocalStorage

`localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");`

// Retrieving info from LocalStorage

`document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("lastname");`

// At the end, when you're done with the data. Just run

`localStorage.clear();`

**So to answer you:**

```
var imageData = window.URL.createObjectURL(image)
localStorage.setItem(imageData) // You can put this in a variable an use it.
```

***UPDATE: If that doesnt work take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7596515/how-to-save-the-window-url-createobjecturl-result-for-future-use), it wont be using LocalStorage as you want, but it could help.***